# Problem using djongo for django 2.1.5 and mongodb 4

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I followed the tutorials of installing both mongodb and django. I also installed djongo using pip and updated my settings.py file in my project. But, when I ran python manage.py runserver I get there are no users authenticated error.I need to get it working in a short time so somebody help me. Did I miss something?

```
    Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fc412ba6400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 56, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 51, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/introspection.py", line 46, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.collection_names(False)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 715, in collection_names
    nameOnly=True, **kws)]
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 677, in list_collections
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 631, in _list_collections
    session=tmp_session)["cursor"]
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 514, in _command
    client=self.__client)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 579, in command
    unacknowledged=unacknowledged)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 150, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/home/habib/.local/share/virtualenvs/habib-HN5dLoHi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: there are no users authenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched the net for hours but still wasn't able to solve the problem. I noticed the mongodb on my other pc was version 3.4 and it used to work well with django as djongo it's connector. So, I downgraded mongodb to 3.4 and purged all the 4.0 versions. That fixed the djongo problem. I guess it doesn't work well with mongodb 4.0.

```
$ sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | $ $ sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mongodb-org
```